# SQL SUM statement in VBA function

Tags: ms-access

My database has three tables, Holder, Product (which is an account) and Transaction. I have set up a form from the Holder table that has a subform from the Product table and the Product subform has the Transaction table as a subform. On the Holder portion of the form, I have put an Outstanding unbound text field that should display the total amount and tax fields of transactions from the transaction table that have not been paid (indicated by a checkbox on the Transaction table). I have set the control source of the unbound text box to =calcOutstanding() and written the following function for the form.

Public Function calcOutstanding()

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT SUM(tblTransaction.TxAmount + tblTransaction.TxTax) As Outstanding" _
    & "FROM tblTransaction" _
    & "INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblTransaction.fkProductID = tblProduct.ProductID" _
    & "INNER JOIN tblHolder ON tblProduct.fkHolderID = tblHolder.HolderID" _
    & "WHERE tblTransaction.TxPaid = False" _
    & "AND tlbHolder.HolderID = Me.HolderID;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

calcOutstanding = Outstanding
```

End Function

The field now just shows #Error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include `Debug.Print strSQL` on the line before `DoCmd.RunSQL` ... and then look at the satement your giving to Access.  First notice there is no space between *Outstanding* and *FROM*.

Comment: Use the Access query designer to create and test your query.  It will add the required parentheses in the proper positions for a query whose `FROM` includes more that one join.

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL` is for "action" queries.  Use something else for your `SELECT` query.  Make that choice based on what you want to do with the results the query returns.

Comment: The results are just to be used in the text field of the form. Which commands are specific to SELECT queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch wrong with your approach:

1. DoCmd.RunSQL is just for action queries (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).
2. You cannot return a value from DoCmd.RunSQL like you are attempting to and push it into a variable.
3. Your concatenation for the where clause is incorrect.
4. As HansUp mentioned, Access is very picky about parentheses in JOINs in its SQL.

Assuming the SQL is correct, this code lives on the parent form, and you dno't get multiple rows back in your query, maybe something like this would work:

```
Public Function calcOutstanding() As Currency

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    strSQL = "SELECT SUM(tblTransaction.TxAmount + tblTransaction.TxTax) As Outstanding " _
        & "FROM (tblTransaction " _
        & "INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblTransaction.fkProductID = tblProduct.ProductID) " _
        & "INNER JOIN tblHolder ON tblProduct.fkHolderID = tblHolder.HolderID " _
        & "WHERE tblTransaction.TxPaid = False " _
        & "AND tlbHolder.HolderID = " & Me.HolderID

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbForwardOnly)

    calcOutstanding = rst![Outstanding]

    Set rst = Nothing
    set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Notice the concatenation in the WHERE clause to get the value from the form's data source (otherwise the SQL couldn't reconcile Me.HolderID within the scope of the SQL itself).  Also, we push the returning dataset into a recordset and read from that.  Something along these lines should work, I think.  (Not in front of Access now, so sorry if any non-compiling statements.)

**EDIT**: Added the function return type as integer for specificity's sake.
**EDIT 2**: Added the function return type as currencyfor specificity's sake.  Doh.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I corrected the concatenation error in the SQL WHERE clause, but unfortunately, there could be multiple transactions involved in the outstanding that a holder may have.

Comment: Ok, so do you want to deal with that in SQL or do you want to do a cursor-based solution by going through each of multiple rows in the recordset returned above?  The general framework of the solution is still solid, in any case.

Comment: I would prefer to deal with it in SQL. From what I gather, the above SQL statement will go through the entire Transaction table and sum the TXAmount and TxTax fields for all records that are not marked as paid and the match the current holderID on the form. Is that correct.

Comment: From my perspective, yes, that is correct.  And return one row with the result of al that.

Comment: Oh, if it is returning a row, it will not work as the control source for a text box. I just need the value of the variable Outstanding, which I assumed would be the value of the sum function, to be displayed in the text box.

Comment: Yes, while one row is pushed into the Recordset object, only one value is returned by the function.  It's this line here: calcOutstanding = rst![Outstanding].

Comment: I'm not sure why it's still showing an error then. I've checked my data types and TxAmount, TxTax, and Outstanding are all of the type Currency.

Comment: Oh sorry, the return type should be Currency as well.  My fault, wasn't thinking.  But that is probably not your error.  Are you sure your SQL is correct?  Does it run properly if you cut ans paste into a query?  I will edit my code to a Currency return type.

Comment: `OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbForwardOnly)` triggers error #3001, *"Invalid argument"*.  Change it to `OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly)`

Comment: I finally got the query running properly and copied the SQL that access produced from it: SELECT Sum(tblTransaction.TxAmount+tblTransaction.TxTax) AS Outstanding
FROM (tblHolder INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblHolder.HolderID = tblProduct.fkHolderID) INNER JOIN tblTransaction ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblTransaction.fkProductID
WHERE (((tblTransaction.TxPaid)=False) AND ((tblHolder.HolderID)="C0000000001")); However, the function itself is still causing a #Error in the unbound field

Comment: Nevermind, it was something silly. I added the quotation marks around the Me.HolderID criteria at the end of the SQL statement and it's working fine now. I feel silly now. Thank you so much for  your help.

Comment: Oops, I assumed HolderID was an numeric type.  Sorry about that.   All good, glad you got your code working!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you need an external function to do this. MS Access allows you to reference fields from subform simply by Me.Subform!FieldName.Value

This means, you could simply access the subform fields that are related to your current record. Even perform **IIF(condition, truevalue, falsevalue)** on that field

read more about accessing forms and subforms here: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

**EDIT:**
in your third subform (tbl_transaction), create a new unbound TextBox called (txt_outstanding) and assign this expression

```
=IIF([txPaid]=false, sum(txAMount +TxTax),0)
```

now you can access this field in your parent form something similar to this:

```
me.txt_someTextbox.value = nz(me.tbltransactionsubform!txt_outstanding.value,"")
```

Comment: Would I need a nested IIF statement to search the transaction table for a specific Holders transactions and then only the transactions that have not been marked as paid?

Comment: @sphere Since you have master,child forms your tbl_transaction from will always have records [only] related to your parent table. this means you only need to perform one check. Whether the tax is paid or not and then sum the amount

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I see a problem in the code you posted:

```
strSQL = "SELECT SUM(tblTransaction.TxAmount + tblTransaction.TxTax) As Outstanding" _
& "FROM tblTransaction" _
& "INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblTransaction.fkProductID = tblProduct.ProductID" _
& "INNER JOIN tblHolder ON tblProduct.fkHolderID = tblHolder.HolderID" _
& "WHERE tblTransaction.TxPaid = False" _
& "AND tlbHolder.HolderID = Me.HolderID;"
```

There should be a space either at the end of each line `Outstanding " _` or at the beginning of each line like `" FROM tblTransaction` otherwise your string will read `OutstandingFROM tblTransaction` when parsed, which will give you an error.

Comment: I've added spaces to the ends of all the SQL statement lines and still have an error.

Comment: @Sphere There's another problem, now that I look at it in more detail: DoCmd.RunSQL only works with Action queries. This is the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626(v=office.15).aspx In your case, you probably want to use CurrentDb.Execute instead

Comment: Actually, CurrentDb.Execute is also limited to Action queries. You need to use DAO to access data and return a recordset. More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff820966.aspx I will edit my answer to address the problem later today.